# How to boot xenomai on ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu, xenomai

I install xenomai by

```
sudo apt-get install xenomai-*
```

It installed

```
dctrl-tools libxenomai-dev libxenomai1 linux-patch-xenomai xenomai-doc xenomai-runtime.
```

But when I check `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, it seems it didn't change anything.

How do I boot `xenomai` on Ubuntu 10.04?

Should I followed [Building Debian packages](http://www.xenomai.org/index.php/Building_Debian_packages)'s Building a Xenomai patched Linux kernel package?

But it uses kernel 2.6.35, which is newer than mine (2.6.32).

Thank you~

Answer (score 1):

While I have no idea about Xenomai, the `linux-patch-xenomai` package includes several `README` files in `/usr/share/doc/linux-patch-xenomai/` that might help you.  (From what I understand, you are to build a new -patched- kernel anyway, so which kernel you're using right now shouldn't matter much.)

Answer (score 1):

I found a detailed explanation on this page. Hope it works for you!

http://code.google.com/p/jhu-lcsr-ros-pkg/wiki/UbuntuXenomai

Comment: Please make your answers more than just a link. If you could provide at least a summary of the solution then your answer is able to stand on it's own if the link ever goes away!